# Remove lines from frame in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, frame

I want to remove the lines from the frame leaving only the three coordinate axes and the lines that make up the 'floor'.

[image]

Comment: In Plot3D use the option `Boxed -> {Bottom}`; also, to highlight the axes add `AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.005], Black]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and the speed of response. Excellent forum, very useful. Greetings from Argentina.

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot3D[x*y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Boxed -> {Left, Bottom, Back}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and the speed of response. Excellent forum, very useful. Greetings from Argentina.